Not able to run the parallel test in selenium
I have a driver hook where the WebDriver is set up. I want to run tests in parallel, but currently, only one browser is opened and all test activities run in that same browser, causing my test cases to fail.
Testng file :

driver hook class
public class DriverHooks {
private static final String homeDirPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");

public static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webdriver = new ThreadLocal<>();

public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    if (webdriver.get() == null) {
        createLocalDriver();
    }
    return webdriver.get();
}

public static void setupDriver() {
    if (webdriver.get() == null) {
        createLocalDriver();
    }
}

private static void createLocalDriver() {
    try {
        quitDriver();
        if (webdriver.get() == null) {
            String downloadFilepath = homeDirPath + FileGetParams.paramLookUp("downloadsPath");
            LogAndErrorHandler.Instance().LogInfo(downloadFilepath);
            switch (FileGetParams.paramLookUp("BROWSER").toUpperCase()) {
              
                case "EDGE":
                case "CHROME":
                    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs",
                            new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                                put("permissions.default.camera", 1);
                            }}
                    );
                    if (System.getenv("WINDOW_SIZE") != null)
                        chromeOptions.addArguments(System.getenv("WINDOW_SIZE"));
                    else chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
                    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                    try {
                        webdriver.set(new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;
            }
            if (webdriver.get() != null) {
                webdriver.get().manage().deleteAllCookies();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogAndErrorHandler.Instance().LogError(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void quitDriver() {
    if (webdriver.get() != null) {
        webdriver.get().quit();
        webdriver.remove();
    }
}


You need to create two theads.  Have your class extend Thread.  Your tests will run in the run method of the thread.  (or execute method to run if extending SwingWorker...)  Thread: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html    I prefer SwingWorker as you've got more functionality built in for progress and finish (doInBackground, done, process, publish methods): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

so you could pass in args for creating the driver and use a factory style class that returns a new WebDriver instance when initializing each instance of your class that extends Thread or SwingWorker.  For classes that extend Thread use .start(), that'll execute run() method.  For classes that extend SwingWorker, use .execute(), which will run doInBackground() method.
